# Find email addresses of all logged in Onedrive/Sharepoint accounts in Windows 11

Tags: python, powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

I am looking for some way to get a list with an email address for each logged in Onedrive account using powershell or python? I would like to ensure that the resultant email address is part of allowed users for a service.

If this is not possible, I'd settle for some way to list "sharepoint only" mapped drives using a script?

Cheers for any help!

**UPDATE**
When trying @Baljeetsingh Sucharia's suggestion I am getting no returned values

[image]

yet the sharepoint drives are clearly in 'my computer
[image]

still lost :(

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of email addresses for logged-in OneDrive accounts using PowerShell, you can use the OneDrive for Business cmdlets that are included in the SharePoint Online Management Shell.

You can use the following command to get the list of all users that have OneDrive for Business accounts:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com
```

This will return a list of all users in your tenant that have OneDrive for Business accounts, including their email addresses. You can then filter this list to only include the email addresses of users who are allowed to use your service.

Alternatively, you can use the following command to get a list of all "SharePoint only" mapped drives:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem | ? {$_.Provider -eq "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem"}
```

This will return a list of all mapped drives on the computer, you can filter this list to include only drives that have SharePoint in their name.

In Python, you can use libraries such as office365-python-client to interact with SharePoint and OneDrive for Business resources and retrieve the email addresses of the users.

You would need to have the appropriate permissions to access SharePoint and OneDrive for Business resources in order to run the above commands or use the libraries.

Comment: Cheers for the reply
The first option I had already but I wanted to have an equivelant command to check what account is being used locally (ie on the pc)
The second option is still returning a blank list even though a sharepoint drive is available. Cheers though

Comment: @DaraOh are you sure you have admin privileges while you are running ?

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this. See update above